# Function pointer template number of arguments

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

So I want to have a function pointer that is passed into a templated method/class but I would like to be able to figure out how many arguments the function pointer takes. Is there anyway to do this without the use of c++11. I have access to boost.
for example:

```
int test(int a, int b, int c){...}


template <typename F> templatedF(F func){
 if(numArgs == ){do this}
}


templatedF(&test);
```

Or is the only way to accomplish this to write out explicit template instantiations that have the number of args I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[boost function_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html) tells you the arity of a function.

I looked at the source and it has partial specializations for up to 10 arguments; as far as I know, there really is no other way to do it in C++03, and using the boost header just saves you from doing the work.